# Best practice with coding system values

Tags: enums, domain-driven-design, database-schema

I think this should be an easy one, but haven't found any clear answer, on what would the best practice be.

In an application, we keep current status of an order (open, canceled, shipped, closed ...). 
This variables cannot change without code change, but application should meet the following criteria:

1. status names should be easily displayed in different languages,
2. application can search via freetext status names (like googling for "open")
3. status_id should be available to developer via enum
4. zero headache when adding new statuses

Possible ways we have tackled this so far:

1. having DB table status with PK(id, language_id) and a separate enum which represents this statuses in an application.
   **PROS:** 1.,2.,3. work out of the box, **CONS:** 4. needs to run update script on every client installation, SQL selects can become large and cumbersome, when dealing with a lot of code tables
2. having just enum:
   **PROS:** 3.,4. **CONS:** 1.,2. is a total nightmare
3. having enums, which populate database tables on each start of an application:
   **PROS:** 1.,2.,3.,4. work **CONS:** some overhead on application start, SQL select can become large and cumbersome, when dealing a lot code tables.

What is the most common way of tackling this problem?

Comment: Thanks for the tip of synching Enums to database on app launch (or through some other reliable mechanism). I came upon this question when searching for best strategies for handling Enums in code & database. My concern has always been with synchronisation of Enum Ids/Keys. With _that_ headache, why even put them in the database you ask? The importance (or need) of having the Enum values ALSO stored in (or synched to) the database is so that db-access-only people (like DBA's, or other applications sharing the database) will also know what the various Enum key values relate to when doing queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you summarized it pretty good yourself, and comparing the pros/cons points towards #3. Just one comment when you implement #3 though:

Use a caching mechanism (even a simple HashMap!) plus adding the option to refresh the cache - will ease your work when you'll want to change values (without the need to restart every time!).

Comment: I guess you're right, now all I need to do is just implement it :)

Answer (score 0):

I would, and do, use method 3 because it is the best of the lot.  You can use resource files to store the translations in and map the enum values to keys in the resource files.  Your database can contain the id of the enum for the status.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly, in #3 I proposed having status texts in database. How should my status table look like?

Answer (score 0):

1.status names should be easily displayed in different languages,
2.application can search via freetext status names (like googling for "open")

These are interfaces layer's concern, you'd better not mix them in you domain model.

I would setup a mapping between status enum and i18n codes. the mapping could be stored in a file (cached in memory) or hardcoded.

for example: if you use dto or view adatper to render your ui.

```
public class OrderDetailViewAdapter {
     private Order order;

     public String getStatus() {
         return i18nMapper.to(order.getStatus());//use hardcoded switch case or file impl
     }
}
```

Or you could done this before you populating you dtos.

You could use a similar solution for goal2. When user types text, find corresponding enum from mapping and use enum for search.

Anyway, use db tables the less the better.

Comment: Searching fulltext presents a tiny problem, user searches for "open john deer", then I would need to rewrite this to "open status=1 john deer" (there might be a legitimate customer with name open:)), which on the other hand, might work, but then my searcher class would need to be aware of the context it is searching through.

Comment: @zeldi I guess multilingua status text search is required since they need to be displayed in different languages?

Comment: I know in advance in which language the person will be using search, so from DB, I can join the correct language.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I always use dedicated enum class inside domain. Only responsibility of this class is holding status **name** (OPEN, CANCELED, SHIPPED, ...). Status name is not visible outside codebase. Also, status could be also stored inside database field as string (varchar or similar).

For the purpose of rendering, depending of number of use cases, sometimes I implement formatting inside formatter (e.g. OrderFormatter::formatStatusName(), OrderFormatter::formatAbbreviatedStatusName(), ...). If formatting is needed often I create dedicated class with all formatting styles needed (OrderStatusFormatter::short(), OrderStatusFormatter::abbriviated()...). Of course, internal mapping is needed to map status name to status title, and this is tricky part. But if you want layering you can't avoid mapping.

Translation is not dealt so far. I translate strings inside templates so formatters are clean of that responsibility. To summarize:

1. enum inside domain model
2. formatter inside presentation layer
3. translation inside template

There is no need to create special table for order status translations. Better choice would be to implement generic translation mechanism, seperated from your business code.

Comment: the only issue with this approach is fulltext database search (req#2), if user searches for "open zevnik", I should get all open orders by customers zevnik, that's the headache I have at the moment :(

Comment: You could make some kind of read model to fulfill that search issue and update it periodically or event based. Also, you could use standalone product for indexing/searching like Solr/Lucene, ElasticSearch...